# Wingpanel translates with touches

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, touchscreen

Just repetitively touching a menu e.g. the power button on the wingpanel and touching somewhere else on the screen causes translation of the wingpanel. I can reset the position by running `killall wingpanel`, but I think this is a bug. I'd be interested to know how to fix it.

[image: Reproduction of the error.]

**UPDATE:** This was fixed in https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/227.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this issue on all the touch screen terminals I have running with Juno. I don't know how to fix it, but I did setup a keyboard shortcut to "pkill wingpanel" so staff can reset it if the problem occurs.

Comment: That's a nice way to make it a little more convenient to get around this bug. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Report this as a bug on the git for Elementary OS. https://github.com/elementary It is probably because of Gtk-3.0 or Vala language which they use to write the code for the wingpanel or something else, maybe even of the firmware for touch screen. Hard to say.

Comment: This was reported as a bug and has already been resolved a long time ago: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/227

Comment: Yup. You're right. It's fixed now. I'll edit the question.